# svn checkout: No repository found

Tags: svn, repository, svn-checkout, svnserve

I noticed that SVN works well until I restart my machine (Mac OS X). Then, when I do `svn checkout svn://10.0.0.9/testA`, I get the error `svn: No repository found in 'svn://10.0.0.9/testA'`.

`svn info` produces the following:

```
Path: .
URL: svn://10.0.0.9/testA
Repository Root: svn://10.0.0.9
Repository UUID: e5a0987c-ab12-4088-82c5-263f6c00c66a
Revision: 3
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: Mika
Last Changed Rev: 3
Last Changed Date: 2013-03-15 14:55:57 +0400 (Fri, 15 Mar 2013)
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: you can see here .This might be the [solution](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/general-10/subversion-no-repository-found-623128/) for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I find that I need to kill the `svnserve` process and start it again.

On the terminal:

//finding and killing the process

```
ps -ef  | grep svnserve
sudo kill processID.
```

just a real world example looks like below:

```
root@debian:/home/arun# ps -ef | grep svnserv
root      2697     1  0 13:23 ?        00:00:00 svnserve -d
root      2935  2574  0 14:20 pts/1    00:00:00 grep svnserv
root@debian:/home/arun# kill 2697
```

//start server

```
svnserve -d -r <path to repository>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of `/testA` path (shortened path) in URL of repository you have to fix -r (repository root) value

From [doc](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup-svnserve.html):

> You can also increase security and save time entering URLs with
>   svnserve by using the --root switch to set the root location and
>   restrict access to a specified directory on the server:

`svnserve.exe --daemon --root drive:\path\to\repository\root`

drive:\path\to\repository\root is path to the parent dir of repository (repositories), not to repository itself